# How do I write an Angular 2 service with CORS in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2, angular-http

I'm having trouble moving my Angular 1 JavaScript service to a Angular 2 TypeScript service using http to make a CORS request (this is using Ionic version 2). In Angular 1, I do something like this.

```
angular.module('app.services',[])
.factory('LoginService', ['$http', function($http) { 
 var service = {};

 service.isUserLoggedIn = function() {
  var restUrl = 'http://10.10.10.25:8080/api/user/isloggedin';
  var options = {
   method: 'GET', url: restUrl, withCredentials: true,
   headers: { 
    'x-request-with': 'XMLHttpRequest', 
    'x-access-token': 'sometoken' 
   }
  };
  return $http(options);
 };

 return service;
}])
```

In Angular 2 using TypeScript, a lot has changed (Promises/Observables). My attempt so far looks like the following.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response, RequestMethod, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  constructor(private _http:Http) {

  }

  isLoggedIn():boolean {
    var r:any;
    var e:any;
    let url = 'http://10.10.10.25:8080/api/user/isloggedin';
    let options:RequestOptionsArgs = {
      url: url,
      method: RequestMethod.Get,
      search: null,
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'x-access-token' : 'sometoken'
      }),
      body: null
    };
    this._http.get(url, options).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError)
      .subscribe(
       response => { r = <any>response; console.log(r); }, 
       error => { e = <any>error; console.log(e); });
    return false;
  }

  private extractData(response:Response) {
    let body = response.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }

  private handleError(error:any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.log('error = ' + errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

I am no longer sure how to address in Angular 2 what I had in Angular 1

- withCredentials (note that https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html#!#withCredentials-anchor says the `RequestOptionsArgs` should have a field `withCredentials` but I get an error in the IDE Visual Studio Code saying that it does not exists in the interface; ionic is probably using an older angular 2 version?)
- <s>headers (x-request-with and x-access-token)</s>
- <s>the actual response</s>

I did a little bit more searching, and I was able to understand how to insert headers and properly handle the subscription. However, the withCredentials is still a problem.

I found this SO post [angular2 xhrfields withcredentials true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007572/angular2-xhrfields-withcredentials-true) and modified my constructor as follows. It works now.

```
constructor(@Inject(Http) private _http:Http) {
    let _build = (<any> _http)._backend._browserXHR.build;
    (<any> _http)._backend._browserXHR.build = () => {
      let _xhr = _build();
      _xhr.withCredentails = true;
      return _xhr;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The support of `withCredentails` will be present in the RC2 version of Angular2 that will be released soon. It's not part of the RC1 version... You need to wait a bit.

With RC2, you will be able to use this property directly in the request options:

```
this.get('...', { withCredentials: true })
```

See this question for more details:

- [Angular 2 - http get withCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681807/angular-2-http-get-withcredentials/37681900#37681900)