# Angular 2 authentication using cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, angular

I inherited an ASP.NET MVC3 app using forms authentication with sessionID and ASPXAUTH in cookies. Now I am trying to replace the Razor view frontend with an Angular 2 app.

I have setup Angular to call the backend once upon first page load to obtain a sessionID from ASP.NET (ngOnInit in auth component). The sessionID is returned as a JSON response. I have made sure to add some "dummy data" to the session to avoid it being re-generated by default for "not being used" in the backend. I then set this sessionID inside a cookie at the frontend using the "ng2-cookie" library.

This works fine, but the sessionID on the backend keeps changing for every request I make. There must be something wrong at the "Angular end", since the sessionID won't change if I manually visit the backend API endpoint (/Api/Account/Login) in the browser.

My gut is telling me that Angular is not passing the cookie to the backend.

I have read about `withCredentials` in Angular 1, but can't find the corresponding solution for Angular 2.

- Is the purpose of withCredentials to forward cookie data to the API/target?
- Can withCredentials be implemented in Angular 2?
- If withCredentials is not an option, how do I pass the cookie along to the backend?

**Update: Still re-generates sessions**

I have followed the instructions for RC1 but it still won't work.

I created `CustomBrowserXhr.ts` and added the following code to it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserXhr } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class CustomBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {

constructor() {}

build(): any {

    let xhr = super.build();

    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    return <any>(xhr);

}

}
```

In my `main.ts` where I bootstrap the application:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, BrowserXhr } from '@angular/http';
import { TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS, TranslateService, TranslatePipe, TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import { provide, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { LoggerService } from './services/LoggerService';
import { CustomBrowserXhr } from './helpers/CustomBrowserXhr'; // Not needed after RC2

// Enable production mode
enableProdMode();

// Import our main angular component
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';

// Bootstrap it to angular
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
HTTP_PROVIDERS,
provide(BrowserXhr, { useClass: CustomBrowserXhr }),
provide(TranslateLoader, {
    useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'app/languages', '.json'),
    deps: [Http]
}),
TranslateService,
LoggerService
]);
```

My `AuthService` makes the call like this:

```
getSession() {

    return this._http.get(appSettings.apiUrl + 'Account/Login', {headers: this.headers})
                .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                .do(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

And in my backend, the request is handeled like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
    {

        #if DEBUG
            // Just for development: Angular calls from ":3000" to .NET = fails origin check
            Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        #endif

        // Grab session for the calling user
        this._sessionID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;

        // Assign something to the session to avoid it being re-generated on EVERY request
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["api"] = 1;

        // Setup JSON feedback
        var feedback = new
        {
            success = true,
            session = this._sessionID
        };

        return Json(feedback, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

This returns a sessionID in JSON and as "Set-Cookie" in the headers. They are equal to each other.

But on the next request, I get a brand new sessionID again.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824994/how-do-i-write-an-angular-2-service-with-cors-in-ionic

Comment: Thanks! Can I put that injectable extension of BrowserXhr inside my "main.ts" file where I bootstrap the application?

Comment: I still can't get this to work. I have updated my original question with some code.

Comment: `withCredentials` should now be supported with the just released RC.2

Comment: Updating to RC2 and `this.get('...', { withCredentials: true })` solved the problem. Thank you very much!